# PHP shell_exec doesn't work in Windows Azure

Tags: php, azure, shell-exec

We need to execute an .exe file in a remote **Windows Azure Server**.

We call it from PHP with **shell_exec**. The .exe should create new files in two different folders into the server and generate data entries in a data base and returns a string, but it doesn’t work.

We don’t have any problem executing it in our local server with windows 7 Enterprise and IIS 7. That’s why we thought it could be a permissions problem, and then we have created a **.user.ini** file with the following content:
**safe_mode= off**
**safe_mode_exec_dir= off**

Unfortunately it doesn’t work too.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably working with [Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/). This is a high-density shared hosting with tightened security. If you need things like `shell_exec` you shall move to [Windows Azure Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) (Web Role), where you have full control over the OS and web server / php settings.

Using Cloud Service you will be able to use `shell_exec`. However when you move to Cloud Service you have begin thinking of saving files in Azure Blob Storage, as the local storage for cloud service is:

- Not persistent
- not synchronized across role instances

If you want don't yet know what `Role` and `Role Instance` is, or are little confused, please go through [this article](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/12/windows-azure-basics-part-1-of-n.html).

Comment: Thank you very much Anton. We appreciate your help but we have changed to Amazon EC2.

All seems to be easier. Easier to learn, easier to manage, better documentation.

As always happens with Microsoft, the environment, and the interface are beautifull, but only that.

Unfortunatly we don't have much time. Perhaps later we'll test again the Azure.